# re throwing const exception reference

Tags: c++, exception

I have been asked in a multiple-choice question what is doing the following program doing:

```
catch(const std::exception& e){
  throw e;
}
```

I answered that it was rethrowing *e* (answer C). But the answer was apparently wrong.

So what is it doing ? Throwing a copy of *e* (answer D)?

The other possible answer were: A)Handles the exception B) Capture the current stack trace in e

Thanks

Comment: It was a MCQ and my answer had been marked wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`throw` statement makes a copy of its argument. That means `throw e;` slices `e` to its base class (or whatever the static type of `e` is). To re-throw the original exception use `throw;`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yup! That's a great answer. I've given even fewer words, but no explanation what exactly is happening ;) ...

Answer (score 2):

It throws a copy of `e`. Answer D is correct.

To simply re-throw do:

```
catch(const std::exception& e) {
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing *exactly what is says on the tin*: you're re-throwing `e`. Conceptually a value copy of `e` is taken although compilers can optimise away any deep copy if there is no side effect in doing so.

To *guarantee* that no copy is made, just write `throw;`.